# Zoomable Treemap using d3.js v4 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am trying to make zoomable treemap using d3.js, the treemap should zoom in or out when a user uses mousewheel.

I have a json file which contains the data. I am able to draw the treemap but I am not able to zoom in and zoom out. I have tried the following code but it is not working.

I also follow many examples and amongs them I found this example https://codepen.io/figle/details/qapRZQ and https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom.

But it is not working for me. I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code. I am using d3.js version 4.

Here is my code:

```
// create tree
let chart = function() {
  const root = treemap(filteredData);
  const svg = d3.select("svg");
  const g = svg.append('g');

  svg
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]) // add new for zoom and pan
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);

  const leaf = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.descendants()) //root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {return "node-" + d.depth})
    .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')' });

 /* There is other code here in this block working on MouseEvent on leaf. */

  let zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .on('zoom', zoomed);

    function zoomed() {
      d3.select('svg g').attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')' });
      console.log("zoomed");
      console.log(d3.event.transform);
    }

    svg.call(zoom);

  return svg.node();
};
```

The issue is `d3.event.transform` works and able to get the transform value, *but there is no change in the treemap.*

D3.js CDN:

> https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

Comment: Did you try to replace `x0` and `y0` with `x` and `y` in the `zoomed` ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I tried replace it as you mentioned, and also used the d3.event.transform for the transfrom attribute, but the cells collapse on each other when I move the mousewheel. Here is the code, please help check it. https://jsfiddle.net/rensothearin/mya3kq7j/23/